# why does my rails generator template method results in 'file_clash'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, generator

So I'm writing a rails generator to do the most simple of things: copy some model files from a gem's lib/generators/pathways/templates directory into a project in the app/models directory. My possibly mistaken understanding is that the template method is basically a file copy with source/target.

(note that "pathways" is the name of my gem that installs this generator)

Here's the guts of the copy code in the generator:

```
def copy_models
  project_models_location = "#{Rails.root}/app/models/"
  [
    "pathways_experiment.rb",
    ...
  ].each do |filename|
    puts "copying #{filename} to #{project_models_location}"
    template filename, "#{project_models_location}"
  end
end
```

The puts displays what I expected:

> copying pathways_experiment.rb to
>   /Users/meuser/Projects/testing_gem/exp_gem_test/app/models/

however, the call to the `templates` method dumps this output:

> file_clash  app/models

I checked the target directory and there are no files in it, so it doesn't seem to be because the code is trying to overwrite the file.

here's the source of the entire generator in case I simply haven't included or extended the correct classes/modules:

require 'rails/generators'
require 'rails/generators/active_record'

```
module Pathways
  class InstallGenerator < ActiveRecord::Generators::Base
    include Rails::Generators::Migration
    source_root File.expand_path("../templates", __FILE__)

    def code_that_runs
      puts "PATHWAYS: installing models"
      copy_models
    end

    private

    def copy_models
      project_models_location = "#{Rails.root}/app/models/"
      [
        "pathways_experiment.rb",
        ...
      ].each do |filename|
        puts "copying #{filename} to #{project_models_location}"
        template filename, "#{project_models_location}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `template filename, "#{project_models_location}/#{filename}"`?

Comment: what's your question there? :)

Comment: ⇑ should work, does not it?

Comment: ah, interesting. all the examples I found didn't require you to put the file name. I'll give that a shot. thanks!